# Accept git mergetool suggestions

Tags: windows, git, beyondcompare

Our mergetool (BeyondCompare) will suggest merge resolutions and not list these as a conflict.  Is there a way to run git merge to accept these resolutions?

Comment: can you provide more information about the strategy it (BeyondCompare) uses (ie. is it a custom one)? it might be sufficient to directly `git merge` if it provides a public strategy

Comment: Default merge strategy...

Answer (score 2):

Solved it with these entries in .gitconfig:

```
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
        cmd =  \"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 4\\bcomp.exe\" -automerge -reviewconflicts $LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED
        trustExitCode = true
```

This answer was helped along with the comments from this here: [Beyond Compare - automatically merge "conflicted" files in working copy (if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309540/beyond-compare-automatically-merge-conflicted-files-in-working-copy-if-poss)